# What could possibly cause this error when declaring an object inside a class?

Tags: c++, class, oop, objectinstantiation

I'm battling with this assignment :)

I've got two classes: Ocean and Grid.

When I declare an object of the Grid inside the Ocean:

```
unsigned int sharkCount;
Grid grid;
```

The compiler/complainer says:

```
error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'grid'
```

Can you possibly predict what produces this error with the limited info I provided?

It seems that as if the Ocean doesn't like the Grid class. Could this be because of the poor implementation of the grid class. BTW the Grid has a default constructor.

Yet the error happens in compiling time!.

EDIT: They're each in separate header file, and I've included the Grid.h in the Ocean.h.

Comment: Have you also included Ocean.h in Grid.h by mistake? That might cause a problem.

Comment: @James Ok, I'm not gonna program anymore, because I did that :)


Anyways, this doesn't fix my problem.

Edit: actually it did, thanks a lot James. I'll try to figure out why is this problem is exactly happening.

Comment: This happened because of the order they were included. Remember that at the top of each header is an *include guard* which prevents itself from being included twice. Otherwise the headers would recursively include each other forever.

Comment: Is the code you posted pasted verbatim from your code? Did you check you're not missing a semicolon just above the `Grid grid;` definition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first guess would be that the definition of `Grid` simply isn't visible at the point that you've tried to use it in `Ocean`. Typically this happens if you have each in its own file, and haven't used a header to allow each to be "seen" by the other.

Comment: I clarified that in my post, I did include the definition of Grid the The Ocean. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

We need the rest of the source, but there are a couple of possible answers:

- Grid is being overloaded by something via a macro (#define)
- the Grid class definition isn't being included.

Answer (score 1):

In order for Grid to be used in your other class you either need to include the header of the Grid in the header or do a forward declaration of the class and declare it as a pointer in your class then instantiate it in your .cpp file.

```
class Grid;

class Ocean {
   Grid* grid;
};
```

or preferably :

```
class Ocean {
    boost::shared_ptr<Grid> grid;
};
```

Comment: I think it should be `boost::` not `boost:`